# return first and last value in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I return the first and last word from this array?

```
var array2 = ['milk','juice','lemonade','soda','water'];
```

I want it to return "milk-water" with the "-" combinding them.

Im not sure which of the array methods to use for this.

Comment: `array2[0] + '-' + array2[array2.length - 1]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `0` for the first, and `array.length - 1` for the last

```
var firstVal = array2[0];
var lastVal = array2[array2.length - 1]
var combo = firstVal + "-" + lastVal;
```

Comment: question was to combine the two, connected with a dash.

Comment: @Shishdem -- Altho I think OP could handle concatenating them, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = array2[0] + '-' + array2[array2.length-1];
```

Comment: Try to explain your answers.  The "try this" answers aren't as helpful.

Comment: OK, I will, I thought it was self-explanatory

Comment: It is pretty basic, so for most people it would be. However, it's not self explanatory for people that will be looking for these kinds of answers. It's all about making the answer useful for more than just the OP.